# How to compile PHP extension on OS X using SWIG

Tags: php, c, macos, shared-libraries, swig

I have a program written on C and need to use it in the PHP project. I succeed to use SWIG and compiled SO php extension on Ubuntu. Afterwards I've tried to use same SO file on OS X - but php throws following error:

> PHP Error[2]: dl(): Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/extension.so' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/extension.so, 9): no suitable image found.
>   Did find: /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/extension.so: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x02 0x01 0x01 0x00

I suggested that issue caused by compilation on another operation system, and decided to create SO file on OS X. I did following:

```
swig -php extension.i
gcc `php-config --includes` -fpic -c extension_wrap.c extension.c
gcc -shared extension_wrap.o extension.o -o extension.so
```

On Ubuntu these three commands are executed successfully and I'm getting an SO file which works fine with PHP on Ubuntu (but fails on OS X).
  On OS X I'm getting following exception from compiler:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "__efree", referenced from:
>         _SWIG_Php_GetModule in extension_wrap.o
>   .............................................................................................................................
>     "_zval_is_true", referenced from:
>         __wrap_swig_extension_alter_newobject in extension_wrap.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

(I've shortened output a little bit).

I've will appreciate if anybody can advice how to build PHP extension on OS X or to use extension built on Ubuntu.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following sequence of commands produced shared library which can be successfully used with PHP on OS X (10.10):

```
swig -php extension.i
gcc `php-config --includes` -fpic -c extension_wrap.c extension.c
gcc -bundle -bundle_loader /usr/bin/php -dynamic *.o -o extension.so
```

I'm still do not understand how this solution works, but at least it works.